# Weird "cpu clock throttled" syslog message

Tags: 18.04, intel, cpu, overheating, temperature

I'm running an Intel NUC (8i7BEH Kit) with a Core i7. Here is the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` for the first of the 8 logical cores (to give you info on my CPU):

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 142
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8559U CPU @ 2.70GHz
stepping        : 10
microcode       : 0xb4
cpu MHz         : 732.289
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 22
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds
bogomips        : 5424.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

(Didn't include the other 7 for brevity)

I notice in my `/var/log/syslog`, I am getting a lot of this kind of spam:

```
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760239] CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 95846)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760239] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 95846)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760242] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 99770)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760248] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 99770)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760307] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 99770)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760308] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 99770)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760309] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 99770)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760310] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 99770)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760311] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 99770)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.760312] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 99770)
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761141] CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761141] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761143] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761143] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761144] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761145] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761171] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761172] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761199] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Aug 24 07:37:25 nami kernel: [2036132.761200] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Based on the timestamps, this seems to happen exactly every 5 minutes. Here is the version info for my Ubuntu installation:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I am not sure if these errors are harmless. Even if they are, I'd like the logs to not be printed. To me it indicates some sort of hardware issue. But this causes a lot of turnover in my syslogs which obscures other important information. Can someone help me find a solution to the underlying issue? Or if there really isn't one, maybe explain why, and how to silence the logs?

Comment: This means that CPU temperature is too high (near [100 degrees C](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/137979/intel-core-i7-8559u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-50-ghz.html)). Operating CPU on high temperatures leads to lowering clock speed (throttling), it is expected.  Output of `sensors` will give exact temperature value. Or use `psensor` for some long-time period to detect peaks.

Comment: Agree, but suggest to use turbostat (linux-tools-common package) to monitor processor temperatures and such. Suggest: `sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,IRQ --interval 15` as a starting point. The messages are from the kernel, but something like thermald, as a temperature throttling daemon, should be able to prevent getting to that point. Or just limit the maximum CPU frequency manually.

Comment: How can the CPU get to 100C every 5 minutes? And this is during a time when load is pretty low (according to `htop`). Normally I can hear the fans spin up when CPU load gets high, but it doesn't do that here.

Comment: 8th gen processors can set offsets, and trigger therrmal events at lower processor temperatures (I think). delete the `--quiet` command option from the above turbostat command example to get a big spew of information, including power limits and temperature limits and if stuff is enabled or not. when it starts. If  you suspect some false temperature reading causing you log entries, you should get a sense about it from running the turbostat command always, perhaps change the interval to 5 seconds.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks, I ran the command without `--quiet` and got [the following output](https://pastebin.com/dR2MFfNJ). I'm not sure how to interpret it, though.

Comment: that spew of stuff looks O.K.. The 60 degree package temperature, for not much load is a concern. Did you observe any 5 minute periodic rise in temperature and also load (busy %)?

Comment: I wasn't really running any diagnostics at the time, sadly. So I'm not sure. This is my headless server so I don't usually keep an eye on it. As a test I ran `sudo stress --cpu 8 -v --timeout 120s` and got super high temps `99.68   3461    14648   92      29.95` .. thats 92C right? That's crazy.

Comment: Maybe to avoid going too far off topic, I can say at this point it's a real issue and not a misread temperature as I originally thought. And the logs would go away if I can somehow find a better way to cool my CPU. The Intel NUC's default cooling solution is probably not sufficient.

Comment: yes. And the line you listed already shows that the CPU clock is throttled to 3.4 GHz. As a test, try `echo 50 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct` (try other values also), to determine at what limit the CPU can go flat out and not trip thermal throttling.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks again for all your help. If you'd be willing to consolidate your advice into an answer I will gladly accept it as such. I think at this point we can phrase the answer to my question as a series of diagnostic tips I can execute to determine the root cause of the issue. All of the commands you provided were new to me and very helpful.